# Android Studio Emulator Settings

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

The latest Android Studio update 4.1 lets you move the emulator window to the IDE.

I can't seem to find the emulator settings in this toolbar which would let one change the environment variables like signal strength, camera input etc. Only boot options are available.

Any way to access these settings while using the emulator inside Android Studio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:**

With the last Android Studio update (starting with version `Arctic Fox 2020.3.1`) extended controls are available within Android Studio emulator.

**Old answer:**

From official
[Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/10/android-studio-41.html)
:

> You can manage snapshots and common emulator actions like rotating and taking screenshots from within Studio, **but access to the full set of options still requires running the stable emulator**.

So you can't right now.